# What is difference between Eclipse Virgo and Eclipse Gemini?

Tags: java, osgi, eclipse-gemini, eclipse-virgo

Hey,
What is difference between Eclipse Virgo and Eclipse Gemini?
(I understand what OSGI does in general).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the Virgo proposal :

> ### Gemini
>
> **Virgo provides a runtime enterprise application model** on top of Equinox, with integrated application and provisioning support. **The Gemini project at Eclipse.org provides implementations of enterprise capabilities** that can be exploited by such applications. The Virgo kernel provides just the foundational capabilities and depends solely on the Gemini Blueprint Service project. **The Virgo server distribution pre-integrates the Gemini Web Container** and Blueprint Service projects. Additional capabilities provided by Gemini projects can easily be added to the Virgo Server simply by deploying the appropriate bundle provided by those projects.

---

**Resources :**

- [eclipse - virgo](http://www.eclipse.org/proposals/virgo/)

Comment: Honestly, I didn't understand a thing :) It is so theoretical.  Easy words and examples are better.

Comment: You can see things like this. Gemini isn't a server at all, but Virgo is. The gemini implementation can be used as a part of Virgo, but it also can be used as a part of any other web server. Virgo is a packaging of modules, and gemini is one of these modules.

Comment: So, the short answer is: Gemini is more enterprisy?

Answer (score 4):

Eclipse Gemini provides the feature of dependency injection (through Spring) for OSGi bundles. In the other hand, Eclipse Virgo is a OSGi runtime built on the Equinox container that includes a bunch of technologies like Gemini, Logback, P2 or servlet containers (like Jetty or Tomcat).

An alternative for Gemini could be Apache Aries [1] and an alternative for Virgo could be Apache Karaf [2]

- [1] https://aries.apache.org/
- [2] http://karaf.apache.org/